# How to export procedurally generated and animated geometry nodes

Tags: animation, export, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, baking

I have created tentacles for a creature model I made using geometry nodes. These tentacles are procedurally created and a 4D noise texture is scrolled through a set position node in the offset to make the tentacles move. I need to export these tentacles to unity with this animation as well. How can I do this?

I have already tried:

-Applying the geometry nodes which results in the tentacle becoming static

-Just exporting the tentacles results in the tentacles remaining static

-Baking the action also results in the tentacles remaining static when applying geometry nodes

This is my geometry node setup as well:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a technique more compatible with your final goal of exporting. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: The fbx file is unlikely to be the issue. As I mentioned, when exporting as an .fbx the tentacles are exported but they are static and contain no animation. The geometry nodes use blenders engine to animate themselves and therefore I believe I would need to convert these to an actual animated object before exporting in any file type.

Comment: That is correct